# I am using Mosaic to New Raster for AvgMin temp for each month, I need to reference from which month any given pixel in the output was populated from

Tags: raster, arcmap, mosaic, climate, arcgis-10.6

In ArcMap, I am working with climate data, AvgMin for each month. Using Mosaic to New Raster, and Mosaic Operator set to minimum I can isolate the absolute lowest value over the 12 input rasters, however, I need some way to record which month the value was populated from.

Ideally, I would like to see one column with a temperature value, and another with a value ranging from 1-12 to reflect which month the temperature value originated from.

Comment: if i understand the question correctly, possible duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/269536/55203). my answer might help, it's possible using grass (not sure about arcgis though) - take N rasters, make new raster where each cell contains number of raster with minimum value  (1..N) . If you're using ArcGIS or QGIS specifically can you add a tag?

Comment: Thanks Steven. I'll have a look. I am using ArcMap 10.6, but do also use QGis with limited knowledge of scripting. I'm starting to think I may need to go the route of vectorizing the rasters, adding an additional row with a relevant ID, and rasterizing again. A lengthy process, but I have to knuckle down and figure this out.

Comment: Steven Kay, thank you for the help. I used the r.series in Grass and the results are great. I labelled the rasters for each month from 1 to 12 and loaded them in sequence, ran the tool with minimum value and exported the output for further work in Arc. Added a value of 1 to the gridvalues to adjust for the r.series output beginning from 0-11. Now I can vectorize this output and the original temp rasters and run a merge to assign correct temp value to the appropriate month the pixel originated from.